# Nhibernate c# : how to define a join with a surrogate key?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm desperately new at nhibernate.

I'm trying to have a class that's related a (SQL Server 2008) table like this:

Main table:

- Column 1 : ID (int) PK
- Column 2 : LOGIN (nvarchar)
- ...

and having a properties that indicate me if there is any row existing in another table (LEFT JOIN on a surrogate key).

Other Table:

- ...
- Column X : LOGIN (nvarchar)
- ...

But I really have no idea how to tell nhibernate to have the [Main Table].Login column matched with the [Other Table].Login column.

I'm using hbm (xml) nhibernate (not a personnal choice).

And I haven't tried anything yet (except for searching around the web how to do this).

EDIT (05-27):
This seems to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping namespace="xxx.xxx" assembly="xxx" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">

<class name="xxx.xxx.ADUser" table="AD_USER">
  <id name="Id" column="ID">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Login" column="LOGIN"/>
  <property name="Hidden" column="HIDDEN"/>
  <many-to-one name="Resource" column="LOGIN" property-ref="Login" cascade="none" />
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

```
[DataContract()]
public class ADUser : xxx.AbstractPersistentObject
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public virtual string Login { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public virtual bool Hidden { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public virtual AbstractHumanResource Resource { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can LOGIN feature multiple times in the "Other Table", i.e. can a single record in the Main Table have a Collection of "Other Table" records or only one?

Comment: @CSL 0 or 1 time (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it. First, define your domain model:

```
public class Main
{
    public virtual Other Other { get; set; }
    //Id and other properties not shown
}

public class Other
{
    public virtual string Login { get; set; }
    //Id and other properties not shown
}
```

The "Other" class mapping is straightforward:

```
<class name="Other">
  ...
  <property name="Login" unique="true" />
</class>
```

And the main class has just one different bit, the `property-ref`, which does what you want:

```
<class name="Main">
  ...
  <many-to-one name="Other" column="Login" property-ref="Login" />
</class>
```

With this model, you just have to assign the `Other` instance naturally. You can check `Main.Other` for null when needed.

If you need to handle legacy data where there can be a `Main` record with a non-null `Login` but no related record in `Other`, use `not-found="ignore"`.

Comment: Can I avoid the need of creating a "Other" class? I'm really just interested in know if the "row" exist or not.

Comment: No, you can't. But you're thinking in tables and rows instead of classes. Maybe NH is not the right tool for you.

Comment: I have to deal with the tool :S At first I was thinking about using a view + instead of trigger. But since it's not something the rest of the program relies on, I'd better avoiding that work arround.

Comment: Do you know if this will result in me "Resource" property to be always loaded with the full object? Because I will really never do something else than testing "Resource == null" with that property. So if there's a way to avoid useless work on the DB, I'd gladly hear about it.

Comment: Checking for null shouldn't cause initialization. But you can run a profiler and check.